# How to reshape the all related data into columns using R

Tags: r

I am currently using R to do the following analysis.

Found the following all data are interlinked:

```
A-B-C-E
```

But I want to reshape it as 
col1 col2

```
A     B
A     C
A     E
B     C
B     E
C     E
```

Comment: Not clear what you're asking... do you want the combinations of A-B-C-E taken 2 at a time ? so `combn(c("A","B","C","E"),2)`

Comment: to add to @digEmAll's answer: `as.data.frame( t( combn( c("A","B","C","E"), 2 ) ) )` for the desired output

Comment: @ digEmAll and @ Wimpel, Thank you so much! That's exactly I need!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could something like this from scratch:

```
string <- "A-B-C-E"
str_vec <- strsplit(string, "-")[[1]]
n <- length(str_vec)
data.frame(
  col1 = rep(str_vec, n-1:n),
  col2 = str_vec[unlist(sapply(2:n, `:`, n))]
)

  col1 col2
1    A    B
2    A    C
3    A    E
4    B    C
5    B    E
6    C    E
```